# View inside view changes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a UIView inside a UIView, now when I click on button in the nested UIView, I want to refresh the full UIView.

How can I inform the parentView to refresh when a button is pressed?

When I press a button in nested View - view2 - I want to do this in the parent view - view1
userImage.hidden = true

[When there is a button pressed in content view, I want to hide userImage from the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWF7.png)
This content View is actually displaying another View Controller, in that view controller when a button is pressed, I want to update the view

EDIT - The solution I am thinking of is to reload the full View Controller. How can I reload the parentView Controller?

Comment: can show the code

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually ? share some code please

Comment: I have a image in the parent view that I want to remove when the user clicks on a button in the nested view

Comment: add some code and what do you want refresh, the label content or some animation?

Comment: label content, I want to hide the label from parent View

Comment: give some code and image so that people can help you

Comment: added a image, thanks

Comment: You can post a NSNotification Object regarding to hide or unhide the userImage View when you press that button, and add observer for that notification in your parent view's controller object.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can do so by using the **- (void)setNeedsDisplay;** method

```
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: setNeedsDisplay is only recommended when you are using drawRect as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818319/when-do-i-need-to-call-setneedsdisplay-in-ios)

Comment: try **- (void)setNeedsLayout;**

Comment: When I refer the parent view from nested view, it gives, parent view as nil

Comment: Then it's not nested. If you added it as a subview it's supervise is not nil.

Comment: please see the new image added

Comment: Your screen shot does not show the button. In the action method of your button do a `sender.superview?.superview?.setNeedsLayout()` and `sender.superview?.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` if you want it to happen immediately.

Comment: The button is present in the viewController, which is called in the contentView. That is why button is not in the screenshot